# app showing the login page and THEN redirecting to the home

Tags: reactjs, react-router

please, bear with me as it is my first App so I am not very confident.
1-My problem is that when entering my App, I have to show the login button ( I do not have a registration form) where I get the token from google. With that, I can then land on the /home page and inside the App the sidebar has to be shown on every page
2-with the token I get, I have to check in my database if the user is an admin or not. According to these informations, I can show some pages/components or hide them.

The structure I have implemented is this one

```
function App() {
  const [token, setToken] = useState(false);
  const history = useHistory();

  if (!token) {
    return (
      <Login
        setToken={setToken}
        history={history}
      />
    );
  }

return (
    <>
      <Router>
        <Sidebar />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path='/home'>
            <Home />
          </Route>
          <Route exact path='/departments'>
            <DepartmentTable />
          </Route>
          <Route exact path='/users/1'>
            <UserTable />
          </Route>
          <Route extact path='/types'>
            <KindTable />
          </Route>
          <Route exact path='/devices/1'>
            <DeviceTable />
          </Route>
          <Route exact path='/test'>
            <Test />
          </Route>              
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </>
  );
}
```

in the Login component I use the GoogleLogin library

```
const Login = ({ setToken, setNotAuthenticated, history }) => {
  const responseSuccGoogle = async (response) => {
    setToken(true);
    try {
      const { data } = await axios.post(
        "https:xxxx",
        { token: response.tokenId }
      );
      localStorage.setItem("refreshToken", data.refresh_token);
      localStorage.setItem("accessToken", data.access_token);
      history.replace("/home");

      console.log(localStorage.getItem("accessToken"));
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  const responseFailGoogle = (response) => {
    console.log(response);
  };

  return (
    
          <GoogleLogin
            className='gbutton'
            clientId='xxxx'
            buttonText='Login with Google'
            onSuccess={responseSuccGoogle}
            onFailure={responseFailGoogle}
            cookiePolicy={"single_host_origin"}
          />
  );
};
```

what I get is that on successful login, after setting the token I enter the App but NOT in the /home page. How can I achieve that? (first problem)
Furthermore, if I type in the browser http://localhost:3000/home, or /deparments I see the login page and after login, I am redirected there. The fact is that I should not be able to see anything at that address before the login :(

Comment: Is there a question about the code or a specific issue there somewhere in your post?

Comment: sorry, the question was in the wrong format. now you should be able to see it at the very end of my post

Comment: Wait, so you enter your app's address, `http://localhost:3000`, and there's some additional url path in the address bar, and you are wondering why you see the `Login` component and the extra path stuff in the address bar? If you don't want to see that then you should move your `Login` component ***into*** the router and implement authenticated routes which will redirect users back to `"/"` or `"/login"` or whatever you decide is best for your app.

Comment: If I knew how to do that then I would have not asked the question ^^. Said that, if you could please explain a total beginner how to have an App that shows you the login page and that after authentication redirects you to the home page, that would be helpful... including how to do the authenticated routes. Thanks

Comment: Official documentation is a great place to start. `react-router-dom` has a good [auth/redirects example](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/example/auth-workflow) with running codesandbox so you can tinker with it live. There are also many many answered/resolved questions here on SO regarding `react-router` and authentication. If you give an implementation a shot and you are having a hard go at it, please feel free to update your question with the new relevant details.

Comment: add sample in https://codesandbox.io/

Answer (score 0):

In the login component, `history.replace("/home");` is always run,whether you get `{data}` from the axios request or not.

Replace with:

```
if(data){
   setToken(true);
   history.replace("/home");
}
```

Comment: I moved the setToken(true) inside the try block, after I get data back from axios but the result is the same

Comment: forgive me, what should I do exactly with that something?

Comment: Do you have a working repo on github? Is `GoogleLogin` a custom component , or does it come from a package?

Comment: I eventually had it to direct me to the /home. however now I am facing the second problem, i.e. showing a different sidebar based on if the logged-in user is an admin or not. I understood I have to wrap the components in a guest vs protected route but I currently do not know WHERE to set the logic of querying the user's details in the database BEFORE rendering the page :(